# string find and replace with sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, cat

This contains the following information in a file.

```
17:06:31.301 [blabal] DEBUG blablabla1
17:06:31.302 [blabal] DEBUG blablabla2
17:06:31.303 [blabal] DEBUG blablabla3
```

Fetching the contents of that file cat to wonder whether I would like to change it to json format.

```
[{"time" : "17:06:31.301", "log" : "[blabal] DEBUG blablabla1"}
{"time" : "17:06:31.302", "log" : "[blabal] DEBUG blablabla2"}
{"time" : "17:06:31.303", "log" : "[blabal] DEBUG blablabla3"}]
```

Is it possible in this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 's/^([^ ]+) (.*)/{"time" : "\1", "log" : "\2"}/; 1s/^/[/; $s/$/]/' file 
[{"time" : "17:06:31.301", "log" : "[blabal] DEBUG blablabla1"}
{"time" : "17:06:31.302", "log" : "[blabal] DEBUG blablabla2"}
{"time" : "17:06:31.303", "log" : "[blabal] DEBUG blablabla3"}]
```

#### How it works

- `sed -r`

  Start `sed` with extended regular expressions.  For BSD sed, use `-E` in place of `-r`.
- `s/^([^ ]+) (.*)/{"time" : "\1", "log" : "\2"}/`

  Divide the line up into the first word, denoted `\1`, and all the rest, denoted `\2` and then put it into json form.
- `1 s/^/[/`

  On the first line, prepend everything with an opening square bracket `[`.
- `$ s/$/]/`

  On the final line (denoted `$`), locate the end of the line, also denoted by `$`, and put a closing square bracket `]` there.